# Filter Tastypie resource using OR logic

Tags: django, rest, tastypie, query-string

I'm trying to come up with the best way to express an OR query for a `ModelResource` filter.

I'm pretty sure I'll have to override `ModelResource.build_filters()` or `ModelResource.apply_filters()` with something like this.

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(field='foo') | Q(field='bar'))
```

However, I'm at a loss for the best way to express this filter as a GET parameter.  I'd like to be able to `OR` together arbitrary fields as well

```
MyModel.objects.filter(Q(last_name='foo') | Q(first_name='bar'))
```

Any suggestions?